# Putting ListBox in ScrollViewer: mouse wheel does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, scrollviewer

My mouse wheel does not work when putting a `ListBox` in a `ScrollViewer`.

Does the `ListBox` somehow "steal" this event?

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">
<ListBox>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 1</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 2</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 3</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 4</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 5</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 6</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 7</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Edit: as requested by Joel, added the reason why I did this..
I did this because I don't like what the `ListBox`'s internal `ScrollViewer` does with my layout. I have a background image, and on top of that a `ListBox` as shown here:

[alt text http://robbertdam.nl/share/1.png](http://robbertdam.nl/share/1.png)

Now when the scrollbar appears, the following happens:

[alt text http://robbertdam.nl/share/2.png](http://robbertdam.nl/share/2.png)

I've created a Style for a `ScrollViewer` that shows the scroll bar *on top* of the `ListBox` item's content. In the `ListBox` item's datatemplate I've reserved some space for the scrollbar to appear.

Thanks,
Robbert Dam

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly, I think you need to elaborate on what your limitations are and what you're trying to achieve. Without that, I can only explain why what you're doing isn't working. Somebody may even have a better idea about how to get the result you're after.

If you put `ListBox` inside a `ScrollViewer`, then the [control template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) for `ListBox` still has its own `ScrollViewer` inside. When the mouse cursor is over the `ListBox` and you scroll the mousewheel, that event bubbles up until it reaches the `ScrollViewer` that's part of `ListBox`. That one handles it by scrolling and marks the event as handled, so then the `ScrollViewer` you put the `ListBox` inside of ignores the event.

If you make the `ListBox` taller and narrower than the outer `ScrollViewer`, and give it enough items so that the `ListBox` itself can scroll the items, you'll see 2 vertical scroll bars: 1 in the `ListBox`, and 1 outside the `ListBox` for your outer `ScrollViewer`. When the mouse cursor is inside the `ListBox`, the `ListBox` will scroll the items with its internal `ScrollViewer`, and its `Border` will stay in place. When the mouse cursor is outside the `ListBox` and inside the outer `ScrollViewer`, that `ScrollViewer` will scroll its contents -- the `ListBox` -- which you can verify by noting that the `ListBox`'s `Border` changes position.

If you want an outer `ScrollViewer` to scroll the entire `ListBox` control (including the `Border` and not just the items), you'll need to re-style the `ListBox` so that it does not have an internal `ScrollViewer`, but you'll also need to make sure it automatically gets bigger according to its items.

I don't recommend this approach for a couple reasons. It might make sense if there are other controls inside the `ScrollViewer` along with the `ListBox`, but your sample does not indicate that. Also, if you're going to have a lot of items in the `ListBox`, you'll be creating `ListBoxItem`s for every single one, eliminating any advantage that the default, non-re-styled `ListBox` gives you due to the default `VirtualizingStackPanel`.

Please let us know what your actual requirements are.

---

**Edit:** Ok, now I have a little better idea, with the addition of those images. The effect you're getting is that when there are enough items to scroll and the scrollbar appears, the available area has to shrink a bit horizontally because the `ScrollViewer`'s template uses a `Grid`. These seem to be your options, in order of lesser-to-better:

1. Re-style the `ListBox` to not have a `ScrollViewer` and use your re-styled `ScrollViewer` outside the `ListBox`. You'd then also have to force the `ListBox` to also be tall enough to show every item in that same `Style`, and now you've lost UI virtualization. If you're going to be showing hundreds of items in the list, you *definitely* don't want to lose that.
2. Re-style the `ListBox` and set the `ControlTemplate` to use a `ScrollViewer` with the style you already created for it that puts the scrollbar over the content rather than in a separate column. This one's ok (`ListBox` gets to limit its height and use a `VirtualizingStackPanel`, yay), but as you said, it necessitates awareness of that in your `DataTemplate`.
3. Re-style the `ScrollViewer` to leave space for vertical scrollbar even when it is not visible. Here's what this option looks like:

By default, `ScrollViewer` uses 2 columns in a `Grid` equivalent to this:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

So the `Width` of the scrollbar's column is 0 when the scrollbar is not visible since `Width="Auto"`. To leave space for the scrollbar even when it is hidden, we bind the `Width` of that column to the `Width` of the vertical scroll bar:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition
        Width="{Binding ElementName=PART_VerticalScrollBar, Path=Width}" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

So now the `ControlTemplate` in the custom `Style` for `ScrollViewer` might look like this:

```
<ControlTemplate
    TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="{Binding ElementName=PART_VerticalScrollBar, Path=Width}" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition
                Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollContentPresenter />

        <ScrollBar
            Grid.Column="1"
            Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
            Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />
        <ScrollBar
            Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />

    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You could even make the content column a fixed size and the scrollbar column `Width="*"`, which might work better in the long run if your image is not stretched. Now the `DataTemplate` does not have to compenstate for the width of a scrollbar, as it gets a consistent area to use whether the scrollbar is visible or not.

You'll probably want to check out the rest of the [example `ControlTemplate` for `ScrollViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970847.aspx), but those examples are not the default styles. *Note that the example puts the vertical scrollbar on the left! Also note the comment at the bottom about `ContentScrollPresenter`.*

Answer (score 12):

I was dealing with the same issue. I set the *ListBox.ItemsPanel* Property, without any *ScrollViewer*:

```
 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
     <ListBox>
          <ListBox.Template>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                 <Border>
                     <ItemsPresenter />
                 </Border>
             </ControlTemplate>
          </ListBox.Template>
          <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <VirtualizingStackPanel />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <\ListBox>
<\ScrollViewer>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helped me, but the actual fix was not the `ListBox.ItemsPanel` override -- the fix for me was the override of `ListBox.Template`. The `ListBox.ItemsPanel` can stick with whatever you had it before. @Ramin, is your description of the `ListBox.ItemsPanel` override being the fix accurate, or did you mean the `ListBox.Template`?

Answer (score 3):

see this link for another answer:[Scroll in ScrollViewer when mouse over ListBox](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9ce8fabb-165c-468e-8dab-a211c3821da5/scroll-in-scrollviewer-when-mouse-over-listbox?forum=wpf)

Hello, I think you can handle the whole ListBox’s PreviewMouseWheel event. This will also affect individual items as long as you don’t handle each item’s

```
PreviewMouseWheel and mark the event as handled:
    private void ListBox_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            scrollViewer1.LineDown();
        }
        else
        {
            scrollViewer1.LineUp();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make work the mouse scrolling and don't need a style for the ScrollViewer:

- Remove the outer ScrollViewer.
- Use the attached properties of the ScrollViewer, which is inside of the ListBox.

See first two lines of this example:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ListBoxItem>Test 1</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 2</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 3</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 4</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 5</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 6</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>Test 7</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```